# Rails: How to use fullscreen background video?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, background, html5-video

I am making a rails app where I want a fullscreen video in the background. Should I use html5 or .js to do this? If I'm going to use .js, is bigvideo.js any good even though there is no gem for it yet?

Comment: Please mark as correct if the solution works for your project.

Answer (score 0):

Add the jquery plugin Bigvideo.js to your JS folder.
require the plugin in your application.js file
call the plugin at the bottom of your `<body>` tag. This should prepare the page for the js, and then fire the function upon loading the page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
$(function() {
    var BV = new $.BigVideo();
    BV.init();
    BV.show('http://wherevideoislocated.mp4');
});
});
</script>
```